# mongoose schema's custom validator is being called twice

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The following validation is being executed twice and I'm not sure why

```js
activeStatusComment: { 
  type: String, 
  default: '', 
  trim: true, 
  validate: function(v){
    console.log('value: ' + v);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that a plugin 'mongoose-versions' was creating a duplicate document and therefore my validation breakpoint was being hit twice.

The moral of the story is to check your plugins and/or other dependencies in the call stack.